# What is difference between Project Path and Workspace in spring Tool suite?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

There's an option to start a project in Spring Tool Suite we can select our Project path and Workspace. Where I need to choose if I need to save project files?

[image: Annotation-2019-08-07-081010.png]

I need to save files on D:\3rd year\SQA location. Where I need to put this, in Project path or Workspace?

**Updated**
[image: image.png]

In this window when I click "Add a local project" link in below the above window appear.

Comment: screenshot doesn't look like the ones that come with STS out of the box. Where is that from?

Comment: @MartinLippert I update the question and add the previous window. This spring tool suite 4.

Comment: The startup window in the screenshots still doesn't look familiar to me and looks like some other third-party add-ons where installed here. Anyway, I will try to describe a bit the difference between the workspace and the project locations.

Answer (score 1):

The workspace is a concept of Eclipse and contains the metadata for settings and which projects belong to the workspace. You can put your projects into your workspace folder, but you don't have to. You can put your projects anywhere you like. And you can import projects from anywhere into your workspace.

When creating new projects in Eclipse/STS, the wizard usually asks you where to store the project itself. The default is often set to the workspace location, but you can change that and put the project anywhere.

Therefore, in your example, the project path is probably the path where your project itself is stored (or will be stored), whereas the workspace location is the location where your workspace metadata information will be stored.

Hope this helps!